# Highlight only the center feature on openlayers

Tags: openlayers

I'm quite new to openlayers and I was wondering if there was a way to highlight ONLY the center feature of a layer http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/select-features.html

A highlight like the example above would be perfect and although I understand how its done, I have yet to find a way to highlight only the center.

Comment: When you say center, it is just the centroid or within the feature?

Comment: Oh by center I mean the center coordinates of the map itself

Comment: What you could do would be:

1. Create a point at the center of your map, and update it whenever this move
2. Create a style to this point, bright enough to look like it is selected.

If we talk about the center of the map at all times. If not so I have not quite understood the question.

Comment: Do you want to highlight feature, that is in the center of map? So whenever you pan map, new feature will be highlighted (or no feature at all - if there isn't any in the center of map)?